# google maps interative markers how to do?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to use google maps in a web site. I will get data on client side in JSON and based on that data I want to add markers dynamically. More over my requirement is to make markers iteratively. Like in some sites they animate or they are shown with a zoom out effect. [See this example please](http://www.volunteermatch.org/livemap)

Please guide me how to do this. What map API class or functions I should study for this. Please recommend some j-query plug in for interactivity on google maps.

thanks

Comment: hello can any one please guide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good starting point, I recommend these resource:

- [10 jQuery Plugins for Easier Google Map Installation](http://speckyboy.com/2010/02/03/10-jquery-plugins-for-easier-google-map-installation/)
- [jQuery and Google Maps Tutorial](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics)
- [Simplify Google Maps API with Google Maps jQuery Plugin](http://www.webappers.com/2010/01/06/simplify-google-maps-api-with-google-maps-jquery-plugin/)

As a general Google Maps API mega tutorial that covers everything from the basic to the advanced, you can't go wrong with:

[Google Maps API Tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/)

And, I just know you've been to [Google's own large site on using the Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/), right?

Note that you need to make sure that articles and information you're using are the API you're using.  V3 is the current standard, but there are many, many articles and such on using V2.  Just pick the one you're going to use (knowing that V2 is deprecated) and make sure not to get sidetracked by an article using the other.

If you like, you can also see live examples I worked on: [1](http://www.ecu.edu/campusmaps), [2](http://www.ecu.edu/campusmaps/itcs/computerlab.html), [3](http://www.ecu.edu/campusmaps/itcs/smartclassroom.html) using jQuery, JSON retrieval, and marker instantiation.  Note that these use the V2 API.  I also have written [some blog posts about experiences I had using Google Maps](http://www.carolinamantis.com/wordpress/?cat=6) (again, V2).  My posts have several links to the sources of information I consulted when creating those examples.